# Can't vertical align caption on image

Tags: css

Been sitting for the past hour trying to get my hover effect trying to work properly.

I need to vertically align my caption on the image when it's hovered. I tried vertical align on pretty much all the elements, but I can't seem to target it properly.

Comment: I need the captions aligned to each of their image

Comment: where, at the bottom, top, left, right, inside/outside?

Comment: You used absolute positioning. So might aswell use the properties: `top,left,bottom, right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a few lines of code to `figcaption`:

```
figure:hover figcaption {
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    display: flex; /* new */
    justify-content: center;  /* new */
    align-items: center;  /* new */
    pointer-events: none; /* new */
}
```

For more information about flexbox visit:

- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Worked like a charm! For some reason I can't click the images though, you have any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

So you've come across a very common CSS issue that all developers run into at some point: vertical alignment.
There's a couple of different ways to vertically align something, and using each varies per scenario. For a full guide and more information, check out this great article at CSS-Tricks.com:
(https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

For your scenario (and I tried it on your site and it worked) in your CSS I would change it to:

```
 figcaption h3 {
     position:absolute;
     left:50%;
     right:50%;
     transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

and take away the

```
figcaption:hover h3 {
     left:0;
}
```

And that works